# Moving to a next page after a certain time JQuery

Tags: jquery, time, submit

I am trying to move it to another page if the validation is right and the spinning is showing but the transition is fast, the spinning looks not right. How can I hold the spinning for 3 seconds and move it to the next page?

```
   <a type="submit" href="next-to" class="btn submit">
      Next page
      <span class="fa fa-rocket"></span>
    </a>
```

In JQuery, if the validation is right, it will add a loader class to the spin to make it loading and move it to the next.

```
  if (validate()) {
    $('.fa').addClass('loader'); <!-- showing the loading at least 3 seconds
  }
```

Comment: try to add setTimeout() method for redirection after loader added.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, you can use as like below

**Method 1:**

```js
function fnshowLoader(obj) {
  this.event.preventDefault();
  if (true) {     //If true return by validate() function
    $('.fa').addClass('loader');

    var url = obj.getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = url;
    }, 2000);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a type="submit" href="next-to" class="btn submit" onclick="fnshowLoader(this)"> 
      Next page
      <span class="fa fa-rocket"></span>
    </a>
```

**Method 2:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nextPressed').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (true) { // If true return by validate() method
      $('.fa').addClass('loader');
      var url = this.href;
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = url;
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a type="submit" href="next-to" class="btn submit nextPressed"> 
      Next page
      <span class="fa fa-rocket"></span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `setTimeout` like so:

```
if (validate()) {
  $('.fa').addClass('loader'); <!-- showing the loading at least 3 seconds

  setTimeout(function() {
    return;
  }, 5000);
}
```

Also, using "fa" class is not recommended at it will add "loader" class to all the elements with "fa" class. A better way would be `$('.submit.fa-rocket')`

Comment: It should have worked, but going straight to the next page.